# How can I stop Banshee from renaming files during a sync?

Tags: banshee, sync, music, rename, filename

Currently I have sync set automatically and to transcode my flac files into mp3.

For multi-disc albums I have my tracks sometimes like "**1-01 First Song First Disc.flac**" and "**2-01 First Song Second Disc.flac**".

After the sync it would then be "**01 First Song First Disc.mp3**" and "**01 First Song Second Disc.mp3**".

This is a problem with sorting. And currently it screws up how my mp3 player sorts the tracks. I'd just like to make Banshee honor my file names (I do not have the rename files option enabled, or even the write metadata. I use MusicBrainz Picard for tagging.).

Any help is wonderful!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)